# Rspec: How to have factory have two associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Since a Location belongs to an Owner and User in my application I want to build it base off of this fact. So in my factories are like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username   'user1'
    email      'user@example.com'
    timezone   'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
    password   'testing'
  end

  factory :owner do
    name    'Owner One'
    user
  end

  factory :location do
    name 'Location One'
    about 'About this location'
    website 'http://www.locationone.com/'
    phone_number '12 323-4234'
    street_address 'Shibuya, Tokyo, Japan'
    owner
    user
  end
end
```

Than I have my **spec/models/location_spec.rb**

```
describe Location do
  before(:each) do
    @location = FactoryGirl.build(:location)
  end
end
```

Than my model **location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :about. :website, phone_number, 
                  :street_address, owner_id
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

Note: `owner_id` is available because it can be selected.

With all this though it will return the failure of my test with:

```
Failure/Error: @location = FactoryGirl.build(:location) 
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: 
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Email has already been taken, Username
```

I expect this is because the owner first creates the user when it shouldn't and than the location creates the same user. So how would I get around this?

Comment: Could you provide the full definition of the Location model?

Comment: @MattRogers OK, I just did it now.

Comment: What kind of association do you want? Do you want `Location` to belong to a user and an owner?

Comment: @BaylorRae' Yeah, thats correct

Comment: can u describe your table (location, user and owner). May be that will make discussion clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add sequences to my factories. That was it. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username)  { |n| "User#{n}" }
  sequence(:email)     { |n| "User#{n}@example.com"}  
  timezone   'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  password   'testing'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write associations like this

```
User
has_one :locations

Owner
has_one :locations

Location
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :owner
```

Although this association will work and it has **nothing to do with FactoryGirl**. Moreover I feel that this design is not good, why you want owner to be a different field and suppose if a location belongs to users and owners which are different. You can also do this by adding a field is_owner in user models, no need to make different model for owner.

With current info I can tell this much.

Also try changing your factory girl implementation

```
FactoryGirl.define  do
  factory :user, :class=> User do |f|    
    f.username   'user1'
    f.email      'user@example.com'
    f.timezone   'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
    f.password   'testing'  
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :owner do, :class => Owner do |f|
    f.name    'Owner One'
    f.about   ''
    f.private false    
  end 
end
```

Thanks

Comment: That's how I should write in the `spec/models/location_spec.rb`? In my application a `User` and `Owner` are two totally different things. User is their so I know a user added that owner and location. It's a unique design.

Comment: My point is to have my `Location` for my rspec test belong to the Owner and the User. How can I do that?

Comment: @LearningRoR, means you just want to do it for Rspec. In your application you are not using this relationship. Am I right?

Comment: I am using this relationship in my application but in Rspec I want to set it up as I would have it in my application like `user.locations.build` etc. I just don't know how to do both user and owner.

Comment: I guess if you have set up relationship then in rspec no need to use factory girl. You can directly use user.location.create(params)

Comment: if you are using belongs to relationship in locations then there will be owner_id field in locations, put it manually while creating like user.location.create(:owner_id => 1)

Comment: Check my **UPDATE**. I get this error for my `owner` as a Factory. For some reason it's creating the user again when it shouldn't.

Comment: if you using device, i think your device validation is failing. for user give different email, may be this fix

Comment: I think what its doing is creating another user over when I create the owner, when really it should be assigning the user that I created already. That's why I have these two lines: `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }`, `let(:owner) { FactoryGirl.create(:owner) }`

Comment: hey what is user in factory girl definition of owner. hav a look.

Comment: I just got rid of FactoryGirl use altogether and made my question more straightforward and readable.